# Save Object to Internal Storage at Application Install

Tags: android, installation, storage

I would like to know if its possible to save an object at the moment the user is installing the app on mobile.

**Why I want this?**

My app uses some default objects to his normal behaviour, whenever the user starts the App I want that the objests are there to be used. I could certainly just create them each time the user opens the app..
But that might consume a bit of unnecessary time and performance and battery.. If its default, I want to create only once, and then its always there.

I will also use Internal Storage to create new objects of this type, there will be the default ones, that I described above, and there will be also the option to create new ones and save them to use later, on another time that app is launched, but that its fine, I already read something about how to serialize the object and use internal storage to keep them :)

I am just here asking about the first question, create the item only once at the beginning, maybe on the install moment of the app? I was assuming.. but dont know if its possible.

It has been very helpful to have this space for over an year, I have already learned a lot here from you thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides following intent to detect app installation

```
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>  
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
```

If you use these with conjunction with broadcast receiver you will be notified when user install a new app. Problem with this solution is, it will not help you as you are trying to detect your own app installation.

What you could do is every time user launch your app

- check if object exist
- if not create one and write it to internal storage.

in this way it will created once. Depend on type of object you are trying to save you might consider using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [SqlLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) or simply a [file IO](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html). If you are writing Java Object yes serialization is the way to go.

**Update**

If you are planning to get data from network for the first time, depend on the size you can decide,

- Small File: Put it inside Asset folder and ship it with apk.
- large file: if the file size is huge you might consider to ship portion with apk and sync and update rest on a background process or download everything from network

Comment: Hi there minhaz thanks for your reply, yes that is an option I also thought about that, but I would still need to check if the file was there.. that involves create an socket for inputstream and search for the file. I read somewhere that IO Operations at android have great impact at performance, maybe I'm being too rigorous but is not out there a more elegant way to deal with this? Thanks alot in advance..

Comment: Thanks for your update, it will be a small file, it will be three objects of one of my custom classes. Thats the answer I was looking for, putting the file inside the asset folder? can you give me some more information about this? thanks alot

Comment: I create the file I want, serializing it through my IDE and then I put it on the assets folder ? and will always be there , right ?

Comment: Yess it will be part of you apk.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. A Java object exists in memory, so "saving" it when the user installs the app makes little sense. It can't remain in memory unless some process is holding onto it.

If you mean something like a JPEG photo or other data, you can put the data in the directories of your project and then access it as a resource once your app is installed. See the
[Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) API guide.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, maybe I didn't explain very well. When the app starts I want that the objects are already there, they will be default objects to use, do you understand? I could just create them every time the app is launched, but I was looking for other workaround... Maybe create the object and serialize it and store it at internal storage at the moment of installation, and then I would not need to create that object every time. you got it? Thanks ;)